# Vagrant was unable to mount VirtualBox shared folders

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrant-plugin

Current setup: **Virtualbox 5.1.20** with **Vagrant 1.9.3**

Previous working setup: **Virtualbox 5.1.18** with **Vagrant 1.9.3**

I installed the latest version of Virtualbox and tried to start my VM. The folder mounting has stopped working. The same folder mounting works fine in **Virtualbox 5.1.18**. I get the following error message:

> Vagrant was unable to mount VirtualBox shared folders. This is usually because the filesystem "vboxsf" is not available. This filesystem is made available via the VirtualBox Guest Additions and kernel module. Please verify that these guest additions are properly installed in the guest. This is not a bug in Vagrant and is usually caused by a faulty Vagrant box. For context, the command attempted was:
>
> ```
>  mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 keys /keys
> ```
>
> The error output from the command was:
>
> ```
> mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on keys,
> missing codepage or helper program, or other error
> In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so.
> ```

I have tried manually installing `vagrant-vbguest` plugin (via `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`), but that fixed nothing. Downgrading back to 5.1.18 does resolve it, but this isn't ideal moving forward.

How can I get folder mounting working with **Virtualbox 5.1.20** and **Vagrant 1.9.3**?

Comment: This can also happen if you have an old box cached on your host that doesn't support the version of the vbguest plugin you have installed on your computer. [More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51408047/26510)

Answer (score 162, accepted):

**Update**

> Fixed in VirtualBox 5.1.22.

(https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16670)

***Original answer***

In my case a symlink inside the VM was wrong.
Log into the VM:

```
$ vagrant ssh
```

Then:

```
$ ls -lh /sbin/mount.vboxsf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 49 Apr 19 14:05 /sbin/mount.vboxsf -> /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.1.20/other/mount.vboxsf
```

This link is broken. When you look inside /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.1.20/ you see that the subfolder "other" doesn't exists.
This line fixes that:

```
$ sudo ln -sf /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-*/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions/mount.vboxsf /sbin/mount.vboxsf
```

Now logout of the VM:

```
$ exit
```

And check if it works for you:

```
$ vagrant reload
```

***But i can't fix the link because /sbin/mount.vboxsf does not exist inside my box!***

If the link /sbin/mount.vboxsf does not exists in the first place, than the VBoxGuestAdditions couldn't be installed. This can happen if you have not downloaded the matching VirtualBox Extension Pack after you updated VirtualBox (v5.2.18 and up should download it automatically during Virtualbox updates). You can do that now:

- Halt all your running VMs.
- Open the VirtualBox program.
- Start the download of the VirtualBox Extension Pack and install it.
- If you are not being asked if you want to download the VirtualBox Extension Pack, open ->File ->Check for Update, to trigger the download dialog.

If there was no update for the VirtualBox Extension, than it's possible the VBoxGuestAdditions can't be installed because the installer shows a message and the vagrant plugin vbguest can not prompt an answer (this [is "fixed" in vbguest v0.15.0](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest/pull/268)). You can see that in the output of "vagrant up". There should be a line similar to this one:

```
Do you wish to continue? [yes or no]
```

If that is the case you can run the installer manually. To do so, start the box:

```
$ vagrant up
```

Then trigger vbguest to try the installation again but leave the VBoxGuestAdditions ISO mounted afterwards:

```
$ vagrant vbguest --do install --no-cleanup
```

Log into the box:

```
$ vagrant ssh
```

Ran the installer manually:

```
$ sudo /mnt/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

***A last hope: DIY!***

If nothing of the above worked, try to install the guest additions manually:

```
cd /opt
sudo wget -c http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.28/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.1.28.iso -O VBoxGuestAdditions_5.1.28.iso
sudo mount VBoxGuestAdditions_5.1.28.iso -o loop /mnt
sudo sh /mnt/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Comment: Solved the identical issue (incl. versions) for me too, thanks for keeping my downtime this morning to a minimum!

Comment: As an FYI, here is the ticket tracking the fix of this bug https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16670

Comment: This seems to be a temporary fix.  I got the error again after `vagrant reload`

Comment: @FrankHenard have you looked for the symlink in the VM again? Is it broken again? 
And does /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.1.20/ exists inside the VM?

Comment: After the reoccurence, I downgraded to 5.1.18 - problem solved ;)

Comment: Solved my issues as well. Thanks. My environment: VirtualBox 5.1.20, Vagrant 1.8.7 and vagrant-vbguest 0.13.0.

Comment: Thank you! How do you diagnose these guest addition problems, in general? It seems that these break quite often, and I'm left to praying that Google and SO provide some obscure answer.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this a billion times. Looked all day for such a simple answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the thanks and upvotes!
@kevinmm I use Vagrant and VirtualBox daily since a few years. This was my first problem with the guest additions. But i use also the Vagrant plugin vbguest which does a great job with updating the guest additions inside a VM when i have updated VirtualBox.
But VirtualBox has caused me pain often, with breaking compatibility with Vagrant or on OS/filesystem level. So i try updating VirtualBox not to quickly when there is a new version. ;-)

Comment: Thank you Daviz.  I wish I could send you some $$$   Locating this answer saved me during a crisis!!

Comment: Thanks @ThomParkin! Better give the $$$ to doctorswithoutborders.org or another useful NGO.

Comment: Sadly, It didnt work for me, I got

ls -lh /sbin/mount.vboxsf 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 42 Nov  4  2015 /sbin/mount.vboxsf -> /usr/lib64/VBoxGuestAdditions/mount.vboxsf.
I reloaded but the error persists. 
I also upgrade to 5.1.21 following virtualbox.org/ticket/16670 because they said is fixed but the error persists.
I guess I will have to  downgrade to 5.1.18.

Comment: @KimberlyBF, does the directory /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.1.20/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions/ exist inside your VM? Replace the 5.1.20 with the version of the guest additions which you have installed inside your VM.

Comment: have the same issue for VirtualBox 5.1.22 r115126 and Vagrant 1.9.7

Comment: I have the same issue with 5.1.26

Comment: Had the same issue in 5.2.2, but running the installer manually on VB guest additions fixed it.

Comment: Same issue in 5.2.10.. the link seems to be fine `/sbin/mount.vboxsf -> /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.2.10/other/mount.vboxsf`

Comment: @radtek have you checked the link target?: `ls -alh /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.2.10/other/` Does it exist and are the permissions correct?

Comment: @Daviz yes the file was there, not sure about permissions. I destroyed the vm and rebuilt it to fix.

Answer (score 82):

Installing the vbguest plugin worked in my case with VirtualBox 5.2.6 and Vagrant 2.0.1:

`vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`

Comment: Thanks that worked! `VirtualBox 5.2.6` & `Vagrant 2.0.2` gives `GuestAdditions 5.2.6 running --- OK.` now

Comment: This question was for a specific version of virtualbox and vagrant and already stated that for those particular versions the `vagrant-vbguest` plugin did not work.

Comment: Should be the best answer.

Comment: It works for me with `virtualbox 5.2.8` &  `vagrant 2.0.2`. `GuestAdditions 5.2.8` installed.

Comment: This worked for me too - interestingly enough I already had GuestAdditions installed, but after upgrading from Vagrant v1.8 to v2.0 and VirtualBox from 5.1 to 5.2, I started getting the mount error. EVEN after `vagrant plugin update`. Re-installing the plugin this way fixed it for me.

Comment: This worked for me `MacOS 10.13.4` `Virtualbox 5.2.12 and `Vagrant 2.1.1`

Comment: This worked for me.  `Windows 10`, `Vagrant 2.2.5`, `Virtualbox 5.2.32`, `Geerlingguy/CentOS7`.

Comment: This fixed my issue with Virtualbox 6.0.14, and macOS Catalina.

Comment: Yes, it works, but please explain more details. Why you did it and what that do etc

Comment: I got `timed out (https://gems.hashicorp.com/specs.4.8.gz)` error.

Comment: When you already use this plugin sometimes you have to update it after a Virtualbox update: 
`vagrant plugin update vagrant-vbguest`

Comment: And when the `vagrant vbguest --do install` doesn't work update packages inside the box (`vagrant ssh`) first: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Answer (score 10):

For me, the problem was fixed under the following conditions:

**Environment:**

- VirtualBox  version 6.0.4r128413
- Vagrant version 2.2.3

**Steps:**

Go to your project directory from the terminal or command line (`cd`) and run the following commands:

1. `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest` to install the Vagrant VB Guest Plugin
2. `vagrant up`

If you get an error regarding `vboxsf` not being available. Then maybe your VirtualBox Guest Additions are not installed properly. Hopefully, the commands below will fix your problem.

```
vagrant ssh
sudo yum -y install kernel-devel
sudo yum update -y
exit
vagrant halt
vagrant up --provision
```

Answer (score 5):

The accepted did not worked on my case.

My issue was:
Virtualhost guest addition (on guest machine) installed using command (on host machine):

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
```

was not matching the installed version of virtualbox on host machine and I kept getting this error.

[image]

This command (on host machine) helped me to understand more clearly:

```
vagrant vbguest --status
```

It will verify if guest additions on both host and guest machine are consistent.
If you get, ***Guest additions did not match*** warning then SSH into your virtual machine and run the below command first to install the guest additions inside your machine:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11
```

Then, you can force to install the correct version of guest additions on both host and guest using below command:

```
vagrant vbguest --do install
```

You have to reload the virtual machine after that:

```
vagrant reload
```

Now you can confirm if they match using below command again:

```
vagrant vbguest --status
```

[References 1](https://superuser.com/questions/1527811/how-to-find-out-the-right-version-of-virtual-box-guest-additions-for-a-given-ver)
[References 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm)

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me... run the following:

```
vagrant plugin repair
```

Then

```
vagrant plugin expunge --reinstall
```

Then

```
vagrant reload
```

Comment: Careful with this one. It can break your box and your vagrant installation.

Comment: this is perfect. I have no idea why this works but it works and I love you lots for your answer!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

For me the following commands followed by a reboot of the guest system helped:

```
cd /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-*/init  
sudo ./vboxadd setup
```

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29456128/3014879). Referring to this post you need to stop vboxadd before triggering the commands (I didn't do so since I don't know what vboxadd is).

Answer (score 2):

What I had to do was run the following command to add nfs to windows

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-winnfsd
```

Source: https://peshmerge.io/how-to-speed-up-vagrant-on-windows-10-using-nfs/

Answer (score 1):

Removing type: "nfs" from homestead.yaml fixed it for me. Win 10, Vagrant 1.9.7, laravel 5.4, homestead.

Comment: The question is related to a different version of Vagrant and it's failure to work with a specific version of Virtualbox.

Comment: Solved it for me too.. :)

Comment: please note, Removing type: "nfs" is a bad idea, you will have speed issues, the details are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50614748/laravel-homestead-vagrant-virtualbox-slow-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

Run this command:

```
 vagrant vbguest --do install --no-cleanup
```

It is possible that you have the answer (**An error occurred during installation of VirtualBox Guest Additions x.x.x. Some functionality may not work as intended. In most cases it is OK that the "Window System drivers" installation failed.**)

Don't worry, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is for centos7 boxes.
The vbguest additions folder was not being mounted. This is related to the outdated kernel in the box you are using.

Add the following line to your vm definitions:

```
config.vm.define "centos7" do |box| 
   box.vbguest.installer_options = { allow_kernel_upgrade: true }
```

Update your vagrant vm:

```
vagrant up --provision
```

This way the kernel will be updated, and the guest additions mounted and installed.
You will see a reboot in the process.
Source: https://www.puppeteers.net/blog/fixing-vagrant-vbguest-for-the-centos-7-base-box/

Answer (score 0):

For those who land here with almost the same problem as me, below is the solution

### TLDR

- VirtualBox guest fail because of `system is currently not set up to build kernel modules`
- Solution is uninstall `kernel-headers.x86_64 0:3.10.0-862.9.1.el7`
- Then install `kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64`

### Solution

1. `vagrant ssh`
2. `sudo rpm -e kernel-devel-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64`
3. `sudo wget ftp://mirror.switch.ch/pool/4/mirror/scientificlinux/7.0/x86_64/updates/security/kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64.rpm` //download the file
4. `sudo rpm -Uvh kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64.rpm` //use the file downloaded on step 3
5. `exit`
6. `vagrant reload`

### Details: Problem

1. Do **vagrant up** but fail with similar error except

> The error output from the command was:
>
> /sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device

2. Do further reading of the logs and I notice below key words

> Installing Virtualbox Guest Additions 5.2.16 - guest version is 5.1.10
>
> An error occurred during installation of VirtualBox Guest Additions
>
> This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
>
> Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
>
> packages containing the headers are probably: kernel-devel kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64

3. Read logs further

> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:3.10.0-862.9.1.el7 will be installed
>
> No package kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 available.

4. My guest is I need `kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64` to works

### Details: My environment

- bento/centos-7.2
- vagrant version: 2.0.4
- virtual box version: 5.2.16

### Sources

- [How to uninstall kernel header 3.10.0-862](ftp://ftp.wayne.edu/ldp/en/solrhe/chap4sec23.html)
- [How to install kernel header 3.10.0-327](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9aY0sNJYHo)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **vbguest** before loading the machine e after reinstalling the plugin:

```
vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-vbguest
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
vagrant vbguest
vagrant up / vagrant reload
```